# Java - Is every interface an abstract class?

Tags: java, class, methods, interface, abstract

In Java every method in an interface is implicitly abstract. But when at least one method in a class is abstract, that means that this class is abstract. Does that mean, that every interface is an abstract class?

Answer (score 1):

I guess in some sort of way, yes. An `abstract class` can be used as an `interface`.

The issue is that a `class` can only `extends` on other `class`. A class can `implements` any number of `interface`s.

So while `abstract class`es are similar to `interface`s they are very different in reality.

Comment: This is heavily explained and detailed in the possible dup question.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza ah yes, sorry. Hadn't noticed that one - voted to close as dup.

Answer (score 1):

> Does that mean, that every interface is an abstract class?

No.  An interface (in Java 7 and earlier) can have no method implementations and can define no instance fields.  An abstract class can do both.  These are just some of the substantive differences.

Answer (score 1):

> But when at least one method in a class is abstract.

But its not a class,Its interface.

Instead you can say it's an abstract interface.

And finally :**An interface is abstract by definition.**

Answer (score -2):

Yes when i decompiled a interface it had the modifier public abstract interface, and by definition they must be abstract to contain abstract methods.

Comment: abstract interface is not the same as an abstract class.